# Design question?

Tags: python, django, json, pickle

I am building music app, where user can do several tasks including but not limited to listening song, like song, recommend song to a friend and extra.
currently I have this model:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    activity = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

so far I thought about two solutions.
1. saving a string to database. e.g "you listened song xyz".
2. create a dictionary about the activity and save to the database using pickle or json.

e.g.

```
dict_ = {"activity_type":"listening", "song":song_obj}
```

I am leaning to the second implementation, but not quite sure.

so what do you think about those two methods? do you know better way to achieve the goal?

Comment: Do you mean JSON (and not jason)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you need is an enumeration to match a table in your database.

So in your UserActivity table, you will have
userid, activityid, songid, datetime etc etc

Comment: though about that too, but how about if user friends another user, or creates playlist. I will end up having so many nulls.

Comment: +1 imagine trying to code/filter/report on all the different activity types by parsing strings. Ugh. You definitely want short, preferably integer, and definitely unambiguous identifiers for the activities. Build the human-readable descriptions on demand to suit the context where they are displayed.

Comment: This will be a cross reference table, so you will only have users that have songs. You can even extend this by having a playlistid and then you can take the songid out to some other table. There are lot of different ways to do this. Just do no use strings.

Answer (score 0):

What about [GenericForeignKey](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1)? You could have `userid`, `activityid` and `content_object` on your `UserActivity` where `content_object` is a song, an user or something completely different.

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```